# Check if tab exists in TabControl c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I want to dynamically change the Tabs in a Tab Control depending on what options the user selects.

I have followed the example here [TabControl.TabPageCollection.Contains Method (TabPage)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.contains(v=vs.110).aspx)

My code is as follows;

```
private TabPage VulnTab;

VulnTab = new TabPage("Vulnerability");
if (tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(VulnTab) == true)
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = VulnTab;
}
else
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(VulnTab);

    tabControl1.SelectedTab = VulnTab;
    var vuln = new vulnerability();
    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(vuln);
}
```

This is fired on a button click.

On the first run, there is no VulnTab so it creates one successfully. However, on re-clicking the button it creates a new one again, and so on.

I want it to note on the 2nd button click that the tab page already exists and just go there.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is no point in `== true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you are creating completely new page every time.
As you are defining private TabPage object, you could move it to the class (Form?) scope and check if it's null, like in example below:

```
private TabPage VulnTab;

private void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (VulnTab != null)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = VulnTab;
    }
    else
    {
        VulnTab = new TabPage("Vulnerability");
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(VulnTab);

        tabControl1.SelectedTab = VulnTab;
        var vuln = new vulnerability();
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(vuln);
    }
}
```

Of course `ButtonClicked` is just whatever method fires your action of creating and/or changing the tab.

For your future reference: If you create new object (by using keyword `new`) you are creating completely new object. They might be identical, but they are not the same thing, like two apples which look the same aren't the same apple. Only under some specific conditions (object being simple type (numbers, DateTime) or having IEquatable implemented) two objects created in two separate places might be equal to .NET.

Comment: @AdrianBrown please take a look at edit of my answer with deeper explanation what was wrong with your code, so you could avoid such problems in the future.
Also if my answer resolved your problem, please mark it as resolving problem, this helps me a lot ;)

Comment: Many thanks for the detail. Marked as answered (sorry I had to wait for the timer!)

Answer (score 2):

```
VulnTab = new TabPage("Vulnerability");
if (tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(VulnTab) == true)
```

You just created a brand new `TabPage`.  Obviously, that isn't in `TabPages`.

You need to check the existing instance, by only creating it once.

Comment: Not sure I understand you sorry - lets assume a blank TabControl - test if the tab exists (if (tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(VulnTab) == true)) - it doesnt so it creates it and adds it to the TabPages collection. On rechecking TabPages surely it should find it now exists?

Comment: But you're rechecking for a _different_ instance.

Comment: I understand you now - @Dominik Szymański has pointed this out also and I have a solution

Comment: This should have been the answer. Why? because if a tab page is removed it will still be present as a control of the tab control and the VulnTab != NULL will report the tab present even though it is not visible. I know this is an old post but..

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way:

```
if (tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(VulnTab) == true)
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = VulnTab;
}
else
{
    VulnTab = new TabPage("Vulnerability");
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(VulnTab);

    tabControl1.SelectedTab = VulnTab;
    var vuln = new vulnerability();
    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(vuln);
}
```